# Workflow for Entity relationship / relations

Tags: 7, workflows, entities

I have a content type called Blog. I want the end users to be able to add new relations between the blogs, so that we can build a network of related blogs. But the challenges I am facing are

1. Users should be able to add the relations without having the access to edit blogs.
2. The relations(references) added by the users should be monitored. I need to have a workflow around it. Eg : If more than 2 users with the role moderator upvote this relations/reference then it should become public.

I have searched quite a bit for workflow and entity relationship but nothing worthwhile seems to come up. Currently the only option seems to be a combination of relations and workflow module. I haven't used in relations in any projects earlier and would try to avoid it if possible.

Any suggestions or inputs are greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

How about a content type with two [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) fields?  One for each of the two blogs.

Each node of that content type will then be a connector, and you can use the workflow module or perhaps [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) to manage the connections.